# Using SSHMon plugin with Jmeter- Plugin not capturing any stats

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I have been working on Jmeter from quite sometime now and I have been trying to use Jmeter Plugin SSHMon , but I am stuck as even after configuring it completely it simply says "Waiting for samples" and does not render anything on the graph.

I am trying to execute the command on the Linux box and have passed all the relevant parameter for collecting the stats. But still I am not able to capture anything. Any help or pointer will be appreciated.

I also tried connecting the Linux box using Putty and executing the command and the command does work, but when I execute the test the Plugin does not capture anything

[Please find the ScreenShot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oJEJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases the answer lives in [*jmeter.log*](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) file, check it for any suspicious entries, if something is not working most probably there will be a cause identifier there. Also make sure to actually **run your test** as SSHMon is a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) and relies on Sampler Results so if your test is not running - it will not show anything.

As an alternative you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) which has [EXEC metric](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#exec) so you can collect the same numbers, however PerfMon will require [Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md) to be up and running on the remote Linux system.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the pointer, I will check the Jmeter.log file, and yes I did keep the test running so that the Listner can collect the samples but it couldn't capture anything. I will check on the log file and get back if I see anything which I am unable to understand.

Comment: Just checked, there is nothing in the log file which gives any indication on what is wrong with the listner.

Comment: To add to this, since its a pretty simple and straight forward solution which does not seem to we working, I am quiet curious to make it work. So that a solution can be posted for other if they face similar issues

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trail and error I was able to get SSHMon working. Please find the solution below

Ok Guys, so its a lot tricky as you would expect. So I thought that installing the Perfmon Agent on the server made Jmeter collect the stats for SSHMon listner but there is a catch to it. To start off I will let you know that installing the Perfmon Agent on the servers and then using the plugin to collect the stats works smooth. You can definately use this option. But it requires for the Agent to be started everytime you want to run a test and if there are multiple servers you will have to restart on those server. Not sure if there is a way to automate the restart of the agent or to keep it running for a longer time.                    If you are lazy like me or you have installation restriction on the servers or hell bent on using SSHMon then what you need to do is stated below.

You should always start Jmeter with the command line argument --->

jmeter -H "Proxy" -P "Port" -u "UserName" -a "Password"

The arguments are self explanatory. Once you do that Jmeter will be launched, but wait its not done yet!!

When you start executing your test the command prompt in which you have started the Jmeter will prompt for Kerberos UserName [YourUsername]: you have to again Enter you username here, which you use to start Jmeter or login to you system. Followed by this it will prompt you to enter kerberos Password for your UserName: Enter Your Password and Voila!!

The thing is, it happens in the background so you never see what is happening on the Command Prompt you used to start Jmeter. 
Please see below for more clarity.

Kerberos Username[UserName]: UserName Kerberos 
Password for UserName: Password

I have attached the screen shot as well in the question as well as here showing the issue being resolved. Please refer "[Solution ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c4Rs.jpg)". Cheers!!

Hope this helps Guys!! :)

Also please hit up for the answer if it helps you!! :)